# Redirect loop when combining htaccess with permalink wordpress explanation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem redirecting links using htaccess rewrite. Originally I had only the Rewrite Rule part without the WordPress code underneath and it was working fine. Now, after I tried to add a permalink using Wordpress, the link is giving me a redirect loop problem.

Essentially what I want to do is allow the viewers to go straight to 'www.example.com/blog' when they type 'www.example.com'

I think I am missing something because I thought that the rewriteRule would stop the moment

```
RewriteRule ^$ /blog [R=301,L]
```

is processed because of the [L] flag and then other RewriteRules would not be looked at. Can someone help me understand how the server actually go through the steps of the code below?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /blog [R=301,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the line:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /blog [R=301,L]
```

In the htaccess file in your *document root*, not in the `/blog` directory.

Comment: If I put it in the document root, the moment I go to www.example.com/blog, the redirect error will appear then.